# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: axios, electron, vuejs3, electron-packager, laravel-9

Current url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

When I trying to send request to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/`, it provides `CORS error`. But `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` works properly when I trying to call separately in browser. It works properly in separate laravel application. But when it used inside of elecron-js application, it provides `CORS error`. What is the reason for this? How can I solve this issue?

Code:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:9000', { transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
   delete headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
   return data 
}] })
.then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
})
```

Console:

[image]

Network:

[image]

vue: `3.2.31`

axios: `0.25.0`

electron: `17.2.0`

electron-packager: `15.4.0`

laravel: `9.5.1`

Comment: AFAIK a host is the hostname _and_ the port. You have two different hosts here (`127.0.0.1:8000` isn't the same as `127.0.0.1:9000`) so I think that's the reason for the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that you're requesting data from a server that is not from the origin URL.

You can observe in the **Request Headers** section in the Network tab, a header called *Origin*. This is where your request comes from. When the Origin doesn't match the server being requested you get a CORS error. The way to fix this is to tell the server to accept Origin headers that are not only `http://127.0.0.1:9000`. Your error message states:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` controls which Cross Origin request headers it will accept. You need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server to accept an Origin of `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

On Node Express server you do it like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'})
```